# Is it possible to pass my model which I used in a view back to my controller in MVC3?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, model, controller

In my QuestionModel I have:

```
private List<QuestionModel> _questionList = new List<QuestionModel>();
```

Which I use in my view:

```
//GetQuestionList returns the _questionList
foreach (var item in Model.GetQuestionList()){...}
```

I want to acces my model in the controller when I submit my form in the view.
I have tried to add the model as a parameter in de controller function like:

```
public ActionResult SaveData(QuestionModel model){}
```

But I get nothing in it
So my question is, is it possible and how to do it?

Comment: Can we see some code for your view?

Comment: Is it only one specific `QuestionModel` object you are trying to bind back or the whole collection again?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to bind back to the type of `Model` and use a `for` loop not a `for each` loop in your view.